# Non-selectable drop down list

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to have a drop-down list in which non of the items are selectable? So basically, I'm just looking to use it as a way of showing/hiding a list. I don't want any hover highlighting and I don't want to be able to change the selected item.

Could you suggest if this is possible, or if anyone has any other ideas to achieve something similar, could you point me to a good example.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The [`optgroup`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag comes to mind. It has a `disabled` attribute.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="My List" disabled>
    <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>​
```

However, IE 6 and 7 don't respect the `disabled`. Arrgh.  Neither do they listen to the `readonly` attribute slapped on the whole `select`.

You will have to add a `onchange="this.value ='item1';"` fallback for those browsers, which obviously isn't watertight if JavaScript is turned off.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nnmzq/)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to have a drop-down list in which non of the items are selectable?

I have same requirement So I did like this,

```
<select >
    <option value="item1" disabled>Item 1</option>
    <option value="item2" disabled>Item 2</option>
    <option value="item3" disabled>Item 3</option>
    <option value="item4" disabled>Item 4</option>
</select>
```

[On JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnmzq/9/)